# fade out in two fragments in linearlayout not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm trying to switch 2 fragments using some animation. Everything works if I have a layout with just one fragment, but when I add two fragments one after another then this transition does not work.

My activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="myapplication.ScrollingActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/theMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Now I want to change fragment in the MainFrame container, however the result is that the fade out off the fragment is wrong. The content of the first fragment is longer than the second. When the transition is done, it cut the first fragment to size of the second one and then the fade effect is done.
What I want to achieve is that the first fragment is fade out in its full height and then the second fragment is added in its height using animation.

Please note that this works if I dont have the LinearLayout and have only MainFrame, then the fade out/fade in is correct, but the LinearLayout (or constraint layout) just ruins it.

This is the transition code:

```
private void performTransition()
{
    if (isDestroyed())
    {
        return;
    }
    Fragment previousFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MainFrame);
    Fragment nextFragment = BlankFragment2.newInstance();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    long FADE_DEFAULT_TIME = 2000;

    Fade exitFade = new Fade();
    exitFade.setDuration(FADE_DEFAULT_TIME);
    previousFragment.setExitTransition(exitFade);

    Fade enterFade = new Fade();
    enterFade.setStartDelay(FADE_DEFAULT_TIME);
    enterFade.setDuration(FADE_DEFAULT_TIME);
    nextFragment.setEnterTransition(enterFade);

    fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.MainFrame, nextFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

To recreate this issue, just create a new android studio project, select Scrolling activity, then add 3 blank fragments, set the long content to one fragment's textView and observe the behavior.

What to do to have proper fade out/fade in animation in case of a fragments in linearLayout?

Comment: Which "long content" are you referring to? And what is it that you want to achieve? Have two full screen fragments and scroll from one to the other while one of those fragments can be switched with a third fragment?

Comment: Long content - the text in the textView in one fragment. I  have 2 fragments in one screen, Fragment A and B, A is above B. A fragment has fixed height. Fragment B has variable height (thats why I have them in scrollview). Now I want  to change Fragment B to Fragment C, the fragment C has short content - only 1 line of text and this is where the wrong bahavior happens.

Comment: Does it work with the `LinearLayout`, but without the animations?

Comment: Sure, the fragments are changed, that is not the problem, the problem is that the animation is cut to size of the smaller fragment, or better say to the next fragment

Comment: And `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`in your `FrameLayout` wouldn't do the job?

Comment: No it does not help

Comment: It seems that the problem is not with the LinearLayout nor the FrameLayout or fragment but with the ScrollView. It seems that the ScrollView resize itself to the new fragment height in the beginning off the animation, that essentially cut the fragment and the animation is shown only on the new height. Adding android:fillViewport="true" to ScrollView seems to blocked this and now it is working as expected. So now the question is if this is the right solution or is there a better way to do solve this problem?

Comment: If it works and has no side effects, it is the right solution.

Comment: Ok, I will wait for 2 more weeks and if no other solution is found then I will post it as answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to set *android:fillViewport="true" to ScrollView*, because the it seems that the scrollview first resize itself and cut animation on the rest of the screen.